# Is it time for a change of [administration]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Stack Overflow has an [administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administration) tag with several hundred questions (at the time this post was written) that span a whole range of topics, many of which are borderline (or even blatantly) off-topic.

To make a long story short - can we burninate the [administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administration) tag.

Examining the [preliminary tests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/223467):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
   [administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administration) barely describes the content of the question, and may very well be ambiguous. On it's own, it's too wide (e.g., Windows system administration has nothing to do with WordPress administration), and even in conjunction with other tags, it fails to convey the technical field that's being asked about.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
   IMHO, it isn't. Most (if not all) of these questions aren't about programming, but about other (manual?) tasks required to get a system to do something you want it to do. Depending on the technical topic, most, if not all of these questions would be better suited on SuperUser, ServerFault or even WebApps.SE.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
   IMHO, here too, it doesn't. The questions that may be on topic with this tag are probably questions on how to programmatically achieve some administrative objective, e.g., assign permissions to users. Tagging such a question with the appropriate technical tags (e.g., the programming language being used, and [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/permissions)) conveys all the required meaning, and [administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administration) adds nothing.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
   Barely. It does, in the wide sense of "I want to change the behavior of my system", but probably not much more than that. As noted in question #1 - administration of different systems is different, if you'll excuse the tautology, and grouping them together under the same tag adds little to no value.

Some additional supporting arguments/data:

1. Based on [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1536512#resultSets) that I <strike>borrowed</strike> blatantly stole from  Oleg Valter, this tag (at the time of writing) has 1186 questions, out of which 547 (~46%) are already deleted and 276 (23%) are closed. In other words, less than a third of the questions in this tag are still open/viable.
2. Based on [another SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1690024), there are only four questions that only have the [administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administration) tag. One is closed, another two probably should be (didn't vote to close them so I wouldn't sway the burnination process) and another one can definitely use a couple more tags (it's a question about drupal but isn't tagged with [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal)).

Comment: It's in a network of other poor/meh tags, such as [security](25), [admin](20), [web](14), [configuration](12) and [system-administration](12).

Comment: @ErikA I'm not sure if we're "supposed" to handle multiple burninantion requests at once, but FWIW, I'm all for getting rid of all of those.

Comment: Similar tags [tag:admin] (4,472 questions). [tag:administrator] (702 questions)

Comment: Unfortunately, we aren't supposed to handle multiple at once. Just an indicator it's a poor tag that attracts off-topic questions and poor tag usage (and that even though this one only takes one spot, people can fill the rest with poor questions as well)

Comment: I wonder if the right thing to do in this case is to first synonymize [tag:administration], [tag:admin] and [tag:administrator] and then burninnate them all?